# How can I create a folder within a Team Drive with the Google API?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I'm struggling to create a folder within a Team Drive using the Google API PHP Client Library.

I am using a service account and impersonating a user (myself) who is a member of the Team Drive and can list the contents of the drive. However, when I create a folder it always creates it in 'My Drive' rather than the Team Drive specified.

Attempt 1

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
$client->setSubject('user@mydomain.com');

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$folderId = '0AIuzzEYPQu9CUk9PVA';
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => 'New Test Folder',
    'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
    'supportsAllDrives' => true,
    'parents' => ['0AIuzzEYPQu9CUk9PVA']
));
```

Attempt 2

```
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => 'New Test Folder',
    'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
    'supportsAllDrives' => true,
    'driveId' => '0AIuzzEYPQu9CUk9PVA'
));
```

**UPDATE Attempt 3**

```
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => 'Hello 123',
    'supportsAllDrives' => true,
    'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
    'parents' => ['0AIuzzEYPQu9CUk9PVA']
));

$file = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
      'fields' => 'id'));
    printf("Folder ID: %s\n", $file->id);
```

Attempt 3 gives this error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "notFound", "message": "File not found: 0AIuzzEYPQu9CUk9PVA.", "locationType": "parameter", "location": "fileId" } ]

I have read all the (limited) [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-teamdrives) regarding Team Drive and the API and understand that a folder/file within a Team Drive can only have one parent (The Team Drive's ID) so I have tried variations of the parent as an array and string.

The folder is created correctly, just in the wrong place.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The documentation is not very clear on how to handle the creation of folders inside Teamdrives but this are the two things you need to take note of:

1.`'supportsAllDrives' => true,` is part of the optional parameters and not part of the file metadata.
2. Both the `parent` and the `driveId` should be included as part of the metadata

So here is an example on how to achieve this:

```
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$parent = "0AA3C8xRqwerLglUk9PVA"; //Teamdrive ID

//Create new folder
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => 'Test Folder',
    'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',    
    'driveId' => $parent,
    'parents' => array($parent)
));

$optParams = array( 
    'fields' => 'id', 
    'supportsAllDrives' => true,
);

$createdFile = $service->files->create($file, $optParams);
print "Created Folder: ".$createdFile->id;
```

**Please Note:** You will need the client library version 2.1.3 or greater.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. However, I am trying to create a folder within a Team Drive. Not create the Team Drive itself.

Comment: @DannyGreen Ahh! In that case I apologize for not reading properly. I have the flu right now and missed that. Let me check on that and get back to you.

Comment: No worries, thanks I appreciate it. I've updated my question with a third attempt. I think it was going to My Drive because it wasn't accepting the parents parameter. However now it says it can't find the parent.

Comment: @DannyGreen Hey! I did it, Whohooo! I will update my answer shortly. :)

Comment: Thank you! Adding the Team Drive ID as both the "teamDriveId" AND the "parent" was the key that I missed.

Comment: What is the python equivalent to this? I need to do exactly the same thing in python.