# Google Drive API - How to make sub-folder into the Team Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm developing small system using `Google Drive API` with `JAVA`,
I am wondering about the `TeamDrive API` among `Google Drive APIs`.

First of all, I created team drive folder,

## Create Team Drive

```
public static void createTeamDrive(String accessToken) throws IOException {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    TeamDrive teamDriveMetadata = new TeamDrive();
    teamDriveMetadata.setName("Team Drive API Test");
    String requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    TeamDrive teamDrive = getDriveService(accessToken).teamdrives().insert(requestId, teamDriveMetadata).execute();
    System.out.println("[Create TeamDrive] execution time : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
}
```

and then I shared the user.

## Share User

```
public static Permission ShareUser(String teamDriveFolderId, String googleMail, String accessToken) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Permission userPermission = new Permission().setRole("reader")
            .setType("user").setEmailAddress(googleMail)
            .setValue(googleMail).setWithLink(false);
    try {
        userPermission = getDriveService(accessToken).permissions().insert(teamDriveFolderId, userPermission)
                .setSupportsTeamDrives(true).execute();
        System.out.println(userPermission.toPrettyString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.println("[Give Permission] execution time : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
    return userPermission;
}
```

And then I tried to create subfolder using google-drive library several times,
But I failed to create sub-folder continuously.

## Create Sub-folder

```
public static void createSubFolder(String accessToken, String teamDriveFolderId) throws IOException {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    File fileMetaData = new File();
    fileMetaData.setTitle("SubFolder Title ");
    fileMetaData.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");
    fileMetaData.setTeamDriveId(teamDriveFolderId);
    fileMetaData.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(teamDriveFolderId)));
    fileMetaData.set("supportsTeamDrives", true);
    fileMetaData.set("fields", "id");
    File file = null;
    try {
        file = getDriveService(accessToken).files().insert(fileMetaData).execute();
        System.out.println(file.getId());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("[Create Sub folder] execution time : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
}
```

When I call the 'createSubfolderFunction'
I can get 404 response like this.

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "file",
    "locationType" : "other",
    "message" : "File not found: 0AHGrQOmlzQZUUk9PVA",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "File not found: 0AHGrQOmlzQZUUk9PVA"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)

'0AHGrQOmlzQZUUk9PVA' is the exact result from createTeamDrive function.
```

I referred to this question.[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327769/how-can-i-create-a-folder-within-a-team-drive-with-the-google-api)

Please look at my source-code and point out what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I found problem myself,
I should add setSupportTeamDrive(true) when I use the insert method.

```
 file = getDriveService(accessToken).files().insert(fileMetaData).setSupportsTeamDrives(true).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing issue with the your folder Id check its your parent folder id of google drive is correct or not
$folderId = '0AIuzzEYPQu9CUk9PVA';
Id is present in the google drive folder URL, after you open the parent folder