# Google Drive API - Insert a file to a Shared/Team Drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

So I have this code that uploads a file to Google Drive. I am successful uploading it to any **My Drive** folder, but now I wanted it to upload to any **Team Drive** folder. How can I do that? I am using Google Drive API V2 for this one.

I've seen somewhere to use supportAllDrives, but I don't know where to put it.

***index.php***

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'config.php';
$url_array = explode('?', 'http://'.$_SERVER ['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$url = $url_array[0];

require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($url);
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $_SESSION['accessToken'] = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    header('location:'.$url);exit;
} elseif (!isset($_SESSION['accessToken'])) {
    $client->authenticate();
}

$files= array();
$dir = dir('files');
while ($file = $dir->read()) {
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
        $files[] = $file;
    }
}
$dir->close();

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']);
    $service = new Google_DriveService($client);
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $file = new Google_DriveFile(['supportsAllDrives'=>true]);
    foreach ($files as $file_name) {
        $file_path = 'files/'.$file_name;
        $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $file_path);
        $file->setTitle($file_name);
        $file->setDescription('This is a '.$mime_type.' document');
        $file->setMimeType($mime_type);
        
        $parent = new Google_ParentReference(); //previously Google_ParentReference
        $parent->setId('1wj_QbpXn7x0OOJ1Zf4k57BSR5n1uR_xC');//$folderid = determined folder id
        $file->setParents(array($parent));
    
        
        $service->files->insert(
            $file,
            array(
                'data' => file_get_contents($file_path),
                'mimeType' => $mime_type
            )
        );
    }
    finfo_close($finfo);
    header('location:'.$url);exit;
    

}

include 'index.phtml';
```

Comment: you need to upload it to the driveId of the drive you want it loaded to

Comment: Just `$parent->setId('PASTE HERE THE ID OF THE SHARED DRIVE');`

Comment: @ziganotschka I tried that and it's saying File not Found .

Comment: @DaImTo where is that exactly ?

Comment: Because you need to specify `'supportsAllDrives' => true` as was the case in your code before, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327769/how-can-i-create-a-folder-within-a-team-drive-with-the-google-api/45334235#45334235) a sample for v3.

Comment: @ziganotschka I tried adding 'supportAllDrives' => true under here
`$service->files->insert(
            $file,
            array(
                'data' => file_get_contents($file_path),
                'mimeType' => $mime_type
            )
        );`

but it's giving me an unknown parameter 'SupportAllDrives' error  in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\google-api-php-client\src\service\Google_ServiceResource.php

Comment: you still need to add the  driveId

Comment: @DaImTo where do I add the driveId ? where in the code ?

Comment: For starters why arent you using [files.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)?

Comment: @DaImTo i'm using v2 library. it's using files.insert. but now I'm using v3 library and I got it working. but I didn't use your suggested driveId set up

Comment: I would consider switching to V3 before V2 gets shut down.  Just try setting it where you set up the other file metadata after mime type maybe?  $file->setDriveId(your shared drive id);